# Find indexes of equal numpy 2D rows

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a Python list of 2D numpy arrays (all with the same shape) and I want to extract the indexes of equal arrays. I came up with this:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
c = np.array([[3, 4], [1, 2]])
d = np.array([[3, 4], [1, 2]])
e = np.array([[3, 4], [1, 2]])
f = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
g = np.array([[9, 9], [3, 4]])

li = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]

indexes = list(range(len(li)))
equals = []
for i, a_i in enumerate(indexes):
    a_equals = []
    for j, b_i in enumerate(indexes[i+1:]):
        if np.array_equal(li[a_i], li[b_i]):
            del indexes[j]
            a_equals.append(b_i)
    if a_equals:
        equals.append((a_i, *a_equals))

print(equals)
# [(0, 1, 5), (2, 3, 4)]
```

It works (you can assume that none of the 2D arrays are empty) however the solution is clunky and probably slow. Is there a way to do this more elegantly with Numpy?

Comment: Are all those 2D arrays of identical shapes?

Comment: Yes. Always same shape.

Comment: Does the order of rows of the output matter, i.e. what if we get `[(2, 3, 4)  (0, 1, 5)]` instead?

Comment: Order does not matter as the result can easily be sorted by the first index of the tuple afterwards

Comment: you could make some kind of crude hash of the arrays, compare the hashes and then check the arrays as a final step

Comment: ..continuing previous comment.. Turning this into a fully working answer requires a bit of effort and may not be any faster than alternatives provided, but  for the record you can get a hash of an array, `x`, using `x.flags.writeable = False; x_hashed = hash(x.data)`.

Comment: @tsom: what is the higher-level problem you intend to solve?

Comment: I'm writing a unit test to assert that in a list of objects, each object with a 2D-array and score calculated from the array, all objects with the same array has the same score (but not necessarily the other way around).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that the input arrays in the list are of identical shapes, you can concatenate the list of arrays into a single 2D array, with each row representing each element of the input list. This makes the further computations easier and facilitates vectorized operations. The implementation would look something like this -

```
# Concatenate all elements into a 2D array
all_arr = np.concatenate(li).reshape(-1,li[0].size)

# Reduce each row with IDs such that each they represent indexing tuple 
ids = np.ravel_multi_index(all_arr.T,all_arr.max(0)+1)

# Tag each such IDs based on uniqueness against other IDs
_,unqids,C = np.unique(ids,return_inverse=True,return_counts=True)

# Sort the unique IDs and split into groups for final output
sidx = unqids.argsort()

# Mask corresponding to unqids that has ID counts > 1
mask = np.in1d(unqids,np.where(C>1)[0])

# Split masked sorted indices at places corresponding to cumsum-ed counts
out = np.split(sidx[mask[sidx]],C[C>1].cumsum())[:-1]
```

**Note:** If there is a huge number of columns in the concatenated input array `all_arr`, you might want to get the indices `ids` manually using [`np.cumprod`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html), like so -

```
ids = all_arr.dot(np.append(1,(all_arr.max(0)+1)[::-1][:-1].cumprod())[::-1])
```

Comment: This is certainly an all-numpy solution and extremely fast (0.002 sec vs 2 sec for my solution and 2 sec for @gdlmx solution on big input), but the result includes indexes of arrays with frequency 1. The naive solution is to remove all arrays of length 1 from `out`, but is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @tsorn Needed a bit more work. Just added the updated version to cover that requirement, check it out.

Comment: That's clever use of ravel_multi_index to encode the unique subarrays; although I suppose one might run into overflow problems if the arrays become higher-dimensional or their maximum value increases.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn Yeah, that `max` value would one thing OP has to keep in mind. That's a good note for OP! Thanks.

Comment: How is `ids` calculated? I see that it's some sort of hash of the 2D array values and their order, but I don't understand the documentation of ravel_multi_index

Comment: @tsorn That considers/simulates each row of `all_arr` as an indexing tuple of a multidimensional array, whose shape would be one more than the maximum along each column. I think the way `ravel_multi_index` works is it tries to convert each column into one linear index, that's why we had to transpose `all_arr` before feeding it alongwith the desired multi-dimensional array shape to it. The output are linear indices equivalent of such a representative multi-dimensional array. Hope that made sense!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `itertools`

```
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

equals=defaultdict(list)
visited=[]
for a, b in itertools.combinations(enumerate(li), 2):
  if not b[0] in visited and np.array_equal(a[1], b[1]) :
    equals[a[0]].append(b[0])
    visited += (a[0],b[0])

print equals
# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: [1, 5], 2: [3, 4]})
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved elegantly using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author):

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
print(npi.group_by(npi.as_index(li).inverse).split(np.arange(len(li))))
```

I suspect that it is quite likely that finding these indices isn't your end-goal, and that if you play around a little with numpy_indexed, you may find that a more direct route to your end-goal exists.

Indeed, removing the single-count indices is probably best left as a postprocessing step, although you could also use npi.multiplicity > 1 as a pre-processing step